# Unable to Change References Section Title in moderncv

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, moderncv

I'm attempting to write a CV using the moderncv document class with the following preamble:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letter]{moderncv}

% CV Theme Settings

\moderncvtheme[black]{classic}

% Font and Typography Settings

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[babel=true]{microtype}

....
```

For my publications, I have the following code:

```
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plainyr}
\bibliography{publications}
```

When I typeset my CV using the `pdflatex` and `bibtex` dance, my publications show up under the head References. Does anyone know how to change the section heading to Publications? I tried placing a section manually as follows:

```
\section{\textbf{Publications}}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plainyr}
\bibliography{publications}
```

but this only places an empty Publications section and then a section titled References.

Thank you kindly in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since you are using `babel` with the `english` option, , you need to add this

```
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand\refname{Publications}}
```

to the preamble of your document. A complete example (I changed some settings to make the example compilable for everyone, but this is not relevant):

```
\begin{filecontents}{xxyy.bib}
\@misc{A,
  author="Author",
  year="2024"
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[10pt,letter]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[black]{classic}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand\refname{Publications}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{xxyy}

\end{document}
```

[image]